# ADD taxes to buy/sell swap function of uniswap

Tags: uniswap

i want to add taxes in uniswap or pancake swap swapping function not on transfer function , so whenever someone buys or sells my token from uniswap i will transfer those taxes in LP , if anyone knows how to achieve this ?

Comment: [Please see this blog post for more information](https://tradingstrategy.ai/blog/transfer-fees-token-taxes-and-honeypots).

Comment: thankyou mikko for sharing this , if you have any more reference to add tax on buy and sell only , everywhere there is an example of transfer tax if you have specific buy and sell tax then please share , TIA

Comment: [You can find taxed tokens on TradingStrategy website, especially looking daily top tokens on PancakeSwap](https://tradingstrategy.ai/trading-view/top-list/daily-up). Then study the source code of these tokens from bscscan.